# Python stuck in terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am writing a python program in mac terminal. I am just starting with python so I barely know enough. I was trying to do a while loop  and then python stopped starting a new line (I do not know how to better explain the issue). Basically this is what happened :

```
  >>> while i in s :
    ...  while j in x:
    ...   if i == j :
    ...    s.remove(i)
    


    print(s)


^[[A
```

so I keep on pressing enter but the new line >>> is not showing, and the loop is not executing. Even when I press the up arrow it write ^[[A as above instead of showing the previous used command.
Is it glitch? how to fix it?

Comment: Is that snippet syntactially accurate? There appear to be some white space alignment issues. Whitespace is syntax in python.

Comment: We need to see what `s` is in order to answer this question.

Comment: To stop the code from running and get back to the `>>>` prompt, you can press `control + C`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: s is a list of words and x is a string of words. I want to compare and delete the words in s that are equal to any of the words in x. It was a for loop and then it did not remove all the values. So, for one word in x it worked well and removed two equal values in s, but for another word in x it only removed one that is equal to it in s although s had 2 values that were equal. So I thought maybe I try while. I will try more things. As for the terminal getting stuck I tried the Ctrl+ C and it worked . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're actually asking is how to break out of a stuck terminal process.

Normally that's something like `Control + C`, `Control + D`, `Control + Z` depending on your OS.

If you're on a Mac, it's `Command + C`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to write `while`? It seems like you actually mean `for`

Comment: s is a list of words and x is a string of words. I want to compare and delete the words in s that are equal to any of the words in x. It was a for loop and then it did not remove all the values. So, for one word in x it worked well and removed two equal values in s, but for another word in x it only removed one that is equal to it in s although s had 2 values that were equal. So I thought maybe I try while. I will try more things. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is infinite. A For loop or a break statement would help to fix your problem. Since you are new, I suggest reading up on loops.